# Autocompletado en eclipse erróneo

Tags: java, eclipse

Cuando intento por ejemplo poner la siguiente expresión utilizando el ide eclipse:

`import java.util.Scanner;`

En el momento de poner el primer punto eclipse automaticamente me escribe la siguiente frase: `import sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.java_lang_Class;`.

Como puedo hacer para que me siga mostrando recomendaciones pero me deje escribir lo que necesito?

[image: Config content assist][image: Config content assist 2]

Comment: Deberías de desmarcar la opción de activadores de inserción en el menú de asistente de contenido, también configurar las recomendaciones automáticas de Java Content Assist para caracteres específicos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he marcado la opción que dice:
"disable insertion triggers except 'enter'
No se si es la opción a la que te referias pero es la única que me encaja con tu descripción